# How to open a file at the same folder of the ruby script?

Tags: ruby

The following `.rb` script runs fine if excuting at the script's folder:

```
  db = YAML::load(File.open('db.yml'))
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db)
```

The `File.open` will fail if the script is running outside the script folder. How can I supply the script's path to `db.yml`? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
db_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "db.yml")
```

**Edit:** I got a little bit confused with the script folder, this should work now.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself wanting to do this a bunch, you might consider adding the script's directory to your load path (especially in 1.9.2 where "." is no longer in the load path):

```
$: << File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
```